# Getting to know when URL is shared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know when user shares my site on Facebook or Tweets about it after clicking on buttons provided by me - is there ay way to do so using Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a service like [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) or [ShareThis](http://sharethis.com/)?

They both have reporting tools to see how many times a page has been shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) for facebook.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        // you can make an ajax request to save this "Like", it's up to you.
    }
);
```